# Is this cryptographically secure?

Tags: tls, one-time-pad

If I securely (manually) give/put two computer (Alice and Bob) a secret key, they can securely communicate to each other (?)

Alice encrypt a message (maxlength = secret key length) and send it to Bob, with also anther new secret key encrypted with the old one (that was also used for encrypting the message)

Bob can decode the message and the new key, and do the same with Alice.

I'm not into cryptography but I had this idea and I just wanted to know if it was good, at least theoretically..
Practically should be more difficult

Comment: Practically you really should use [TLS(-PSK)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS-PSK) anyways for serious applications.

Comment: Just a moment, I have to copy my Wi-Fi password before I can answer.

Comment: @SEJPM that's fine, but if I need to have a communication only trough two computers I'd prefer this

Comment: TLS does not care about the underlying transport layer as long as it fullfills the same guarantees as TCP (ie it is relieable).

Answer (score 3):

In principle pre-shared keys are perfectly fine.

You tagged the question with one-time-pad. Note that if you want to use a one-time-pad sending a new key won't work because the key you could send in addition to the message would shrink every time and there is no security gain compared to just using the first key.

If you want [rekeying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rekeying) for other reasons there are many proposals with different properties to be found in [this CFRG proposal](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-irtf-cfrg-re-keying-00).

Comment: no, the new key wouldn't shrink because it will be with the same length of the old one

Comment: That's impossible. Your key space must be as large as the message space to achieve perfect secrecy.